# noUiSlider not appearing

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frontend

I've seen a couple questions asked about this but none seem to have been solved. I'm trying to use [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) to implement a sliding bar on my website. However it is not appearing at all. I can clearly see the  when inspecting the page but otherwise it is like it isn't there.

Here's my code:

```js
<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    //$slider.className = 'noUiSlider';
    //$slider.id = 'slider-range';
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: 0,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 100
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HELLO</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='nouislider.css') }}">

</head>
<body>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='nouislider.js') }}"></script>


<div id="slider"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any advice or direction would be awesome. This is exactly how they have it on their website.

Comment: Have you ensured that you've referenced the two files correctly? As in that they're in the same folder as the page?

Comment: Yeah I am. The {{..}} is the jinja templating language I'm using. The .create() seems like it's working because I see the div's classname change to what it should be. But it is not appearing on the page. Some pretty strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem.

I think it's because the `<div>` target for the slider typically has no content, unless you specify formatting for the element, it's not visible.

Try including the default `.css` file provided with the control as a starting point and I think you'll see the slider appear.

Comment: Upvote useful answers rather than mentioning that they were correct in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by making sure to specify a size in the css style when creating the slider div.